# Error when creating a pipeline. "You don’t appear to have an active Azure subscription."

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-server-2020

I'm getting an error when I try to create a pipeline in our Azure DevOps. I've created a service connection for Azure US Gov to Azure Resource Manager that seems to have verified and saved successfully. Tried different browsers / incognito mode with no luck.

Error Message...
"You don’t appear to have an active Azure subscription."

Running version 18.181.31626.1 (Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1.1)

I've configured the service principal with contributor access. The connection appears to verify okay in DevOps when creating the service connection. In this example I'm selecting the option for Docker, though it appears to replicate against any of the options in the list. When selecting any of the options I see the pop out window on the side state "You don’t appear to have an active Azure subscription."

Comment: Could you share some screenshots of your service connection type and the error message screenshots in your pipeline? And have you tried to re-validate your old service connection or recreate your service connection and test again?

Comment: Hi curtis any update?

Comment: Ah sorry I missed the comment here. Validation and recreation did not help. Currently we are working with MS Support for some help and I am waiting on them to do some kind of fix on the back end. Will update as we progress.

Comment: Indeed, they will provide you with detailed instructions to capture the fiddler trace logs or network trace logs and check the backend data for internal issue with the logs you share in high privacy.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow these steps to troubleshoot the error "You don’t appear to have an active Azure subscription".

1.Go to  [https://ms.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Billing/SubscriptionsBlade to](https://ms.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Billing/SubscriptionsBlade%C2%A0to) check if your subscription status is active.

2.Go to  [https://ms.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/TenantPropertiesBlade to](https://ms.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/TenantPropertiesBlade%C2%A0to) check whether the Security defaults is disabled.

**Note**

Remember to switch to your subscription aad in the steps above.

[image]

In addition, when the user is assigned the subscription (access level above contributor) for the first time, it needs time to sync the changes when logging in to Azure DevOps.

Comment: I have already completed these checks and the issue still persists.

Comment: @CurtisGray  I suppose that you could look into the network trace in F12 developer mode to check more inner details  about this error message `You don’t appear to have an active Azure subscription.` InPrivate mode browser.

Comment: So this is a browser error and not an error in the application itself? What kinds of details in network tracing should I be seeing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also getting the same error in Azure US Gov, using an Azure Devops Server (not cloud-based ADO).  I wonder if "under the hood" the pipeline is assuming it's being run against Azure Commercial, and therefore can't see the subscription and/or tenant?

When you create the Service Connection, the first dropdown is "Environment", where you can choose Azure Cloud, Azure US Government, etc.  I don't see any apparent method to specify the cloud when creating a new pipeline, though.

This whole procedure works fine in Azure Commercial, FWIW.